# Reseller Web Application with domain pointing

Tags: subdomain, cpanel

I have not found any exact match for my query so creating this new thread. I am trying to build an application which is going to be work in the following way:

1. seller come to the example.com.
2. Initially they run the applicaiton as seller1.example.com
3. seller buy a domain say seller.com
4. they need to point our cname to their domain panel
5. then they can run the seller portal with seller.com url

Now the queries or concern are as follows:

1. If we dont add the domain which is created by user in my hosting as add on domain will it work?
2. There can be 1000 of user is it convenient add such huge number of add on domain?
3. There are several domain providers. Some provide facility to point NS record, some provide facility to point IP/A record how this can be manage via cpanel APIs.

Any suggestion or pointers will help us a lot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using a shared-web-hosting account yourself, you'll run into problems. Most shared web-hosting accounts use software like cPanel or Plesk which limits the the extent at which you can control your webserver's configuration - things like adding arbitrary hostnames to your account may be disallowed by the company's policy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If we have dedicated hosting will that solve the issue? Is there any way that we wont add add-on domain and still it pointed out in hosting.